# xlsx to pdf with python in an aws lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pdf, aws-lambda, xlsx

I saw websites proposing this service. Can't we mimic it ?

It seems like we always need Windows so we have to make an EC2 to make it work ? I didn't find A `win32` layer for the AWS Lambda.

[xlsx to pdf](https://document.online-convert.com/fr/convertir/xlsx-en-pdf)

Comment: Provided no macro are involved, LibreOffice has a rather acceptable support for xlsx files and can easily export them to pdf files. Automating LibreOffice is far less programmer friendly than automating Excel, but at least it can be used on any well known Linux or BSD system.

Comment: So I have to forget about doing it in python on AWS but I should do a macro on the file ?

Comment: I have just said the opposite... If you can install LibreOffice on the AWS lambda and can find the *magic command line* to ask it to convert an xlsx file to a pdf file. You should google for soffice --headless --convert-to and hopefully find interesting pointers.

Comment: Youpsi, this is why I wanted to reformulate, wasn't sure to get it ^^. Thanks for the advice, I'm gonna see how to install LibreOffice on a AWS Lambda.